# how to make a specific level of a SWT Tree editable

Tags: tree, swt, rcp

I have SWT tree which has child.
Now I want to provide a right click menu and on click of the menu want to make 1st level of the Tree editable (the name of the tree) as shown in the diagram. I want to make Test editable on click of right click menu or any button.

[image]

Already tried with EditingSupport but couldn't able to figure out how to make it editable only for specific level of the tree and that even on click on menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a `TreeViewer`? If so you can use `TreeViewer#editElement(Object element, int column)` to activate the editor on any element of your choice.

> **Edit 1:**
>
> To create a menu on the tree viewer use the following snippet:

```java
MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopUp");
menuMgr.add(new Action("Rename action") {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        viewer.editElement(myObj, 0);
    }
});
Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(viewer.getTree());
viewer.getTree().setMenu(menu);
```